# Matplotlib X ticks label (datetime)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a column of type datetime.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, MinuteLocator, DateFormatter
    from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
    from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

    rng = pd.date_range(start='1970-01-01', end='1970-01-20 00:12:00', freq='1min')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': rng})
    df['Elev'] = np.random.uniform(600, 610, size=len(df))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))

    ax.plot(df\['Time'\], df\['Elev'\], linestyle=':')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=10))
    date_format = DateFormatter("%H:%M")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)

    xlabel = ax.get_xlabel()
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
```

I want to make a graph in which the axis allows hours greater than 24, that is, it shows the hours from the beginning and when it reaches 24:00 the next one is 25:00...

Comment: IIUC, create a column TimeDelta like this, `df['TimeDelta'] = ((df['Time'] - df.loc[0, 'Time']).dt.total_seconds() // 60).astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':00'` then plot TimeDelta as x.